# Changing value of TextBox due to selection of ComboBox VBA Excel

Tags: vba, excel, combobox, textbox

I have a project in which I have to change to value of a textbox to a value that is searched in a workseet against a vlaue that has been selected from a combobox. for example if I select "A" from the combobox the it should search the worksheet "test" find the input for A and change the text box value to 1 as this is the value entered for A. I have looked at some of the other questions that have been asked here but could not seem to get it to work for me. Below is the code that I have been trying to use.

```
Private Sub IDComboBox_Change()
Dim domainRange As Range
Dim listRange As Range
Dim selectedString As Variant
Dim lastRow As Long
If IDComboBox.ListIndex <> -1 Then
    selectedString = IDComboBox.Value
    lastRow = Worksheets("test").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Set listRange = Worksheets("test").Range("A2:A" & lastRow)
    For Each domainRange In listRange
        If domainRange.Value = selectedString Then
            DomainOwnerTestBox.Value = "test"
        End If
    Next domainRange
End If
End Sub
```

Any help would be great. If you need anymore information then please let me know and also please be paient with me as im new to VBA.

Thanks

Comment: Is it work? Is it shown error?

Comment: It does not work. When I select something in the checkbox then it does not put anything into the textbox@Nicolas

Comment: I want to confrim one thing that what type of control you used in your sheet? Form Control or Active X control?

Comment: I am using Active X Control

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code. It uses Excel built-in MATCH function to search for value in column A of worksheet 'test'.

```
Private Sub IDComboBox_Change()
    Dim wks As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim selectedString As Variant
    Dim row As Long
    Dim value As Variant

    Set wks = Worksheets("test")

    If IDComboBox.ListIndex <> -1 Then
        selectedString = IDComboBox.value

        On Error Resume Next
        row = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(selectedString, wks.Columns(1), 0)
        On Error GoTo 0

        If row Then

            value = wks.Cells(row, 2)   '<--- assuming that input values are in column 2.
            DomainOwnerTestBox.value = value

        Else

            'Value not found in the worksheet 'test'

        End If

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: thats for that reply @milek. But I have tried this and it still does not work. could it have something to do with the fact that I am using another _change() for a different combobox to populate the IDComboBox. I dont think it should have anything to do with it but i dont know. It still does not work and I dont understand why. Your code seems to make a lot of sense but I dont know. Any advice?

Comment: Dont worry about what I said. your code works a treat. All I had to do was change the data type of the selectedstring to a Integer and it worked thanks a ton :):)@mielk